# Is it better to allow the users to write the tags with capital letters? (Their starter letters)

Tags: discussion, tagging

I think it would be better if you allow the users to write some specific tags by capital letters. I mean let them write the initial letter of the words with capital letters.
For instance, for specific words such as:
Hadith, Haram, Sunni, Shia, Tafseer and so forth.

Besides I assume that it could help the readers who are not professional (or are not familiar with Islamic expressions) to know that those words mainly are not English words, (in truth they’re related to Fiqh (jurisprudence),  such as Tafseer,  Fiqh, Fatwa and so forth.

On the whole, it would be better if you let the users write some specific tags with capital letters. (their start letters).

Comment: Relevant MSE post: [Is there any reason why tags are lower-cased?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216225/132874)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really see the advantage.  It seems more likely to just open confusion as to which is the "correct" capitalisation for a given word, and in my personal opinion will more often than not just make things look less professional.

Tags are quick and simple tools for catagorisation, and there's really no need to "dumb down" those categories for laymen who might not understand them; capitalization or no, experts in fiqh know well what the [fiqh] tag does (or should) refer to.

On the other hand, if someone doesn't even *understand* the tag, that's a good sign that they wouldn't be interested in the questions *under* that tag.  And for people unfamiliar with them, the tag wikis are already a valuable (and underused) tool for explaining what they mean.

There's no reason to make tags themselves any more complex than they need to be.

Comment: I relatively agree with you (not completely), but it is a logical answer anyway.